# Can't get python exe to run

Tags: python, exe

So i'm having issues getting my python 3.5 script to run as an exe. Here is the code I am using:

```
import base64
import imaplib
import json
import smtplib
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import lxml.html

GOOGLE_ACCOUNTS_BASE_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com'
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = '<FILL ME IN>'
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = '<FILL ME IN>'
GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN = None


def command_to_url(command):
    return '%s/%s' % (GOOGLE_ACCOUNTS_BASE_URL, command)


def url_escape(text):
    return urllib.parse.quote(text, safe='~-._')


def url_unescape(text):
    return urllib.parse.unquote(text)


def url_format_params(params):
    param_fragments = []
    for param in sorted(params.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
        param_fragments.append('%s=%s' % (param[0], url_escape(param[1])))
    return '&'.join(param_fragments)


def generate_permission_url(client_id, scope='https://mail.google.com/'):
    params = {}
    params['client_id'] = client_id
    params['redirect_uri'] = REDIRECT_URI
    params['scope'] = scope
    params['response_type'] = 'code'
    return '%s?%s' % (command_to_url('o/oauth2/auth'), url_format_params(params))


def call_authorize_tokens(client_id, client_secret, authorization_code):
    params = {}
    params['client_id'] = client_id
    params['client_secret'] = client_secret
    params['code'] = authorization_code
    params['redirect_uri'] = REDIRECT_URI
    params['grant_type'] = 'authorization_code'
    request_url = command_to_url('o/oauth2/token')
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request_url, urllib.parse.urlencode(params).encode('UTF-8')).read().decode('UTF-8')
    return json.loads(response)


def call_refresh_token(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token):
    params = {}
    params['client_id'] = client_id
    params['client_secret'] = client_secret
    params['refresh_token'] = refresh_token
    params['grant_type'] = 'refresh_token'
    request_url = command_to_url('o/oauth2/token')
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request_url, urllib.parse.urlencode(params).encode('UTF-8')).read().decode('UTF-8')
    return json.loads(response)


def generate_oauth2_string(username, access_token, as_base64=False):
    auth_string = 'user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1' % (username, access_token)
    if as_base64:
        auth_string = base64.b64encode(auth_string.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')
    return auth_string


def test_imap(user, auth_string):
    imap_conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
    imap_conn.debug = 4
    imap_conn.authenticate('XOAUTH2', lambda x: auth_string)
    imap_conn.select('INBOX')


def test_smpt(user, base64_auth_string):
    smtp_conn = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    smtp_conn.set_debuglevel(True)
    smtp_conn.ehlo('test')
    smtp_conn.starttls()
    smtp_conn.docmd('AUTH', 'XOAUTH2 ' + base64_auth_string)


def get_authorization(google_client_id, google_client_secret):
    scope = "https://mail.google.com/"
    print('Navigate to the following URL to auth:', generate_permission_url(google_client_id, scope))
    authorization_code = input('Enter verification code: ')
    response = call_authorize_tokens(google_client_id, google_client_secret, authorization_code)
    return response['refresh_token'], response['access_token'], response['expires_in']


def refresh_authorization(google_client_id, google_client_secret, refresh_token):
    response = call_refresh_token(google_client_id, google_client_secret, refresh_token)
    return response['access_token'], response['expires_in']


def send_mail(fromaddr, toaddr, subject, message):
    access_token, expires_in = refresh_authorization(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN)
    auth_string = generate_oauth2_string(fromaddr, access_token, as_base64=True)

    msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg.preamble = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'
    msg_alternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg.attach(msg_alternative)
    part_text = MIMEText(lxml.html.fromstring(message).text_content().encode('utf-8'), 'plain', _charset='utf-8')
    part_html = MIMEText(message.encode('utf-8'), 'html', _charset='utf-8')
    msg_alternative.attach(part_text)
    msg_alternative.attach(part_html)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID)
    server.starttls()
    server.docmd('AUTH', 'XOAUTH2 ' + auth_string)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

def main():
    if GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN is None:
        print('No refresh token found, obtaining one')
        refresh_token, access_token, expires_in = get_authorization(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET)
        print('Set the following as your GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN:', refresh_token)
        exit()

    send_mail('--------@gmail.com', '--------@gmail.com',
                'A mail from you from Python',
                '<b>A mail from you from Python</b><br><br>' +
                'So happy to hear from you!')
    input("Success!")

print(__name__)
input("Wait!!")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When i run the code in pyCharm is works great, when i use pyinstaller it creates the exe. When i run the EXE it will open a new cmd prmpt with no text in it, then it closes. Any ideas why it doesn't print the name or "Wait!!" on the screen?
I named the file **main** and it works great in PyCharm.
I'm not familiar with troubleshooting code that works in an IDE and does nothing as an exe. Is there a basic troubleshooting guide for that?

Comment: formatting issue with posted script?  also test this with a simple hello world sample.  if it works with an empty main, it will work with all this stuff (unless there is an underlying error in main.

Comment: simple hello world works great.
i think... it's something to do with the imports

Comment: why is everything indented?

Comment: i copied this post over from notepad++ so i'm guessing it indented it again when i turned it into a code snippet.

Comment: if you think its an import, create sample hello world scripts run through pyinstaller representing each import to narrow culprit?

Comment: Do you get any useful info if you launch the executable from the command line?

Comment: You should also wrap your methods in a `try / except` to help capture the bug. I would go so far as to add logging as well if it is critical. If you do capture with a `try /except` you can then dump the output to a txt file to review after the fact, eg. `myapp.exe > myapp.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Most of the problems are errors caused by imported modules.

Here are two ways I think of

1. Use exception handling and use `traceback.format_exc()` to display the contents when an error occurs.
2. Errors are usually associated with the `sys.stderr`, so you can redirect stderr output a specified format to a specified file or the like.

Example:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from os import startfile
import traceback


DEBUG = True


class CaptureStderr:
    __slots__ = ('debug_flag',
                 'original',
                 'log',)

    def __init__(self, debug_flag=False, log=None):
        self.debug_flag = debug_flag
        self.original = sys.stderr  # Keep track of original
        self.log = log

    def new_log_file(self, log_path: Path = Path('temp.log').resolve()):
        self.log = open(str(log_path), 'w')
        return self.log

    def start(self):
        """ Start filtering and redirecting stderr """
        sys.stderr = self

    def stop(self):
        """ Stop filtering and redirecting stderr """
        sys.stderr = self.original

    def write(self, message: str):
        """ When sys.stderr.write is called, it will re directed here"""
        if not self.debug_flag:
            self.original.write(message)
            self.original.flush()
            return
        if self.log:
            self.log.write(message)


def main():
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:  # method 1
        from .notexistmodule import notexistclass
        # Put modules that you are not sure whether it is 100% import successful on here.
        main()
    except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())

    # method 2: redirect sys.stderr
    cs = CaptureStderr(DEBUG)
    cs.new_log_file(Path('error.log'))
    cs.start()
    from .notexistmodule2 import notexistclass2
    main()
    cs.stop()
    startfile(cs.log.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error in the exe, most likely an import error.

Run your exe like this to see the error:
Create a .bat file to run the exe with the following commands

```
start C:\Path\To\.exe
pause
```

This will stop the command prompt from exiting until you press a key on the keyboard, letting you read the output.